# How to create button delete view in loop for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have a loop for where I create all views and in this loop I have button where I am trying to create delete 1 view if a button has been selected. All the view is in frames and has a linearlayout with a scrollview.

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams deletePartsParams = new        
FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight*7,tenPixelsHeight*7);
deletePartsParams.setMargins(tenPixelsWight * 60, tenPixelsHeight * 20, 0, 0);
deleteOfPart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete);             //Кнопка удалить автозапчасть
deleteOfPart.setClickable(true);
deleteOfPart.setTag(i);

deleteOfPart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});

deleteOfPart.setLayoutParams(deletePartsParams);
mainFrame.addView(deleteOfPart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove view first need to find that view on Main layout, by looping we can get all child view but need identify current view which need to delete, so by comparing childview and delete view tag we can identify it, so simply remove it by mainLinearLayout.removeView(view); method

```
int count = mainLinearLayout.getChildCount();
View view = null;
for(int countI=0; countI<count; countI++) {
    view = layout.getChildAt(countI);
    if(((int) view.getTag()) == ((int) v.getTag())){
        mainLinearLayout.removeView(view);
        break;
    }
}
```

add above code into onClick of deleteOfPart

Comment: It WORKS! Thank you very match for help!

Answer (score 0):

Good day to you aswell kind human. If I understood you well, the code you posted is inside a for-loop and you are creating a various number of views in that loop, for which you want to delete itself on it's clicking.

Inside that `onClick` you have there, try putting `mainFrame.removeView(deleteOfPart);`

Comment: Hello. I was trying to do like this but its interesting - then i clicking on button Delete on first view it delete last view not first ;). I have setTag on this views and check them on Toast  , maybe something using them? I was trying compare with if (v.getTag==Tag views) so to delete it but not working (((

Answer (score 0):

```
     // Заполняем нашими вьюшками и подставляем значения из РейЛиста с данными
    for (  i =0; i<counter;i++) {
        ImageView picture = new ImageView(this); // Фотография автозапчасти
        EditText changeOfQuantity = new EditText(this); // Едит Текст с изменением количества автозапчастей в заказе
        ImageView editeOfQuantity = new ImageView(this); // Кнопка редактировать количество автозапчастей
        deleteOfPart = new ImageView(this); // Кнопка удалить автозапчасть из корзины
        TextView Number =  new TextView(this);   // Номер автозапчасти
        TextView Description =  new TextView(this); //Создаем Вьюшку текста Описание автозапчасти
        TextView Price =  new TextView(this); //Создаем Вьюшку текста цены автозапчасти
        TextView Brand =  new TextView(this); //Создаем Вьюшку текста бренда автозапчасти
        TextView deliveryOfTime =  new TextView(this); //Срок доставки
         mainFrame = new FrameLayout(this);  //Параметры ФреймЛайаута

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutFirstCartParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight*80,tenPixelsHeight*50);
        frameLayoutFirstCartParams.setMargins(0, tenPixelsHeight * 4, 0, 0);         //ФреймЛайаут
        mainFrame.setTag(i);
        mainFrame.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutFirstCartParams);
        mainLinearLayout.addView(mainFrame);

         FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutPictureParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight*15, tenPixelsHeight*15);
        frameLayoutPictureParams.setMargins(tenPixelsWight / 2, tenPixelsHeight, 0, 0);
        picture.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutPictureParams); // Фотография автозапчастей
        picture.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.camera);
        mainFrame.addView(picture);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams numberOfPartParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight*45, tenPixelsHeight*5);
        numberOfPartParams.setMargins(tenPixelsWight * 20, tenPixelsHeight * 11, 0, 0);
        Number.setLayoutParams(numberOfPartParams); // Артикул автозапчасти
        Number.setText("Номер запчасти: " + article.get(i));
        mainFrame.addView(Number);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutDeliveryTextParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight * 45, tenPixelsHeight*5);
        frameLayoutDeliveryTextParams.setMargins(tenPixelsWight * 20, tenPixelsHeight * 6, 0, 0);
        deliveryOfTime.setTextSize(15);         //  Cрок доставки автозапчасти
        deliveryOfTime.setText("Cрок доставки: " + delivery.get(i) + " дней");
        deliveryOfTime.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutDeliveryTextParams);
        mainFrame.addView(deliveryOfTime);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutPriceTextParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight * 25, tenPixelsHeight*5);
        frameLayoutPriceTextParams.setMargins(tenPixelsWight * 60, tenPixelsHeight * 10, 0, 0);
        Price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D50000"));     //  Цена автозапчасти
        Price.setTextSize(20);
        Price.setText(price.get(i));
        Price.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutPriceTextParams);
        mainFrame.addView(Price);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutBrandTextParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight*20, tenPixelsHeight*5);
        frameLayoutBrandTextParams.setMargins(tenPixelsWight * 20, tenPixelsHeight * 15, 0, 0);
        Brand.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D50000"));     //  Бренд автозапчасти
        Brand.setTextSize(20);
        Brand.setText(brand.get(i));
        Brand.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutBrandTextParams);
        mainFrame.addView(Brand);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutEditQuantityParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight*50,tenPixelsHeight*10);
        frameLayoutEditQuantityParams.setMargins(tenPixelsWight / 2, tenPixelsHeight * 20, 0, 0);
        changeOfQuantity.setHint("Изменить количество");   // Изменение количества автозапчастей  в детали
        changeOfQuantity.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutEditQuantityParams);
        mainFrame.addView(changeOfQuantity);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutDescriptionParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight*50,tenPixelsHeight*5);
        frameLayoutDescriptionParams.setMargins(tenPixelsWight * 20, tenPixelsHeight / 4, 0, 0);
        Description.setText(description.get(i));
        Description.setTextSize(20);                                     // Описание автозапчасти
        Description.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        Description.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutDescriptionParams);
        mainFrame.addView(Description);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams EditQuantityParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight*7,tenPixelsHeight*7);
        EditQuantityParams.setMargins(tenPixelsWight * 52, tenPixelsHeight * 20, 0, 0);
        editeOfQuantity.setClickable(true);
        editeOfQuantity.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.undo);           //Кнопка исправить количество
        editeOfQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        editeOfQuantity.setLayoutParams(EditQuantityParams);
        mainFrame.addView(editeOfQuantity);


        FrameLayout.LayoutParams deletePartsParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tenPixelsWight*7,tenPixelsHeight*7);
        deletePartsParams.setMargins(tenPixelsWight * 60, tenPixelsHeight * 20, 0, 0);
        deleteOfPart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete);             //Кнопка удалить автозапчасть
        deleteOfPart.setClickable(true);
        deleteOfPart.setTag(i);

        deleteOfPart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mainFrame.removeView(deleteOfPart);

            }
        });

        deleteOfPart.setLayoutParams(deletePartsParams);
        mainFrame.addView(deleteOfPart);


    }
```